# Is there a plothole in Merlin's character development?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In [chapter 249, page 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl1RRl.png) of *Nanatsu to Naizai*, it is said:

> The supreme deity bestowed the child [Merlin] divine protection able **to nullify any and all manner of** dark curses and **commandments**. (Emphasis of mine).

However, in [chapter 121, page 8 and 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZYqbl.png):

> We can see that Merlin is getting turned rock solid by Galand's Commandment.

Those two facts contradict each other. Is that a plothole, or is there a reasonable explanation somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so basically thanks to [fellow Redditors](https://www.reddit.com/r/NanatsunoTaizai/comments/7y6g4e/merlins_plothole_in_the_story/), that *sounds* like a little plothole. The main reasons expressed there are:

- It is not an immunity, it is an *ability to nullify* Commandments.
- She forgot that she had this protection on her (the blessing happened 3000 years prior to the main story), which explains why she still suffered the effect.

As for "Is it a valid reason to explain something that should have not happened", it is an open question on which everyone might have his opinion.